# WCF Streaming - MessageContract Request does not Reuse types in all referenced assemblies

Tags: wcf, parameters, messagecontract

I have adapted the WCF 'Stream' sample application that is provided by Microsoft to use a Request object that is set up in a Shared Assembly and decorated with the `MessageContract` attributes. This should then be passed in to the `UploadStreamRequest()` method of the service.

The problem is that when I add a service reference to the client and try to call the method, each of the properties of the `MessageContract` object have just been converted to separate parameters.

I have also experimented with the 'Always generate message contracts' option within advanced settings, and although this then changes the method so that it is passed a request object, it has regenerated its own proxy representation of the object (even though I have 'Reuse types in all referenced assemblies' ticked).

Can anybody explain what I am missing here?

Many thanks

Comment: Code is hosted here...

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0By0SjbSrd3h2TjZWVzMzajBJRkE

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I have fixed it ticking the checkbox "Always generate message contracts." when I add the Service Reference.

Hope this helps.